# Find intersection between a mask and a texture picture in python

Tags: python, image, mask, intersection

I would like to find the intersection between my mask that it's like this:

[image]

And the textured image:

[image]

I wanted something like this, but without the blue line (it's just to see more the difference) and without the info in the borders:
[image]

Thanks!!!!

EDIT: That's my code by now:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import derivative
import copy
import skimage.feature.texture
from PIL import Image



class TextureWavelets:
    def access_to_images(self, directory_segmentation: str, directory_originals: str, n_displays: int,
                         color_plaque: str):

        count = 0
        for image_name in os.listdir(directory_originals):
            if count < n_displays:
                segmented_image = cv2.imread(directory_segmentation + "/" + image_name)
                segmented = Image.open(directory_segmentation + "/" + image_name)
                original = Image.open(directory_originals + "/" + image_name)

                masked = self.create_mask_plaque(segmented_image, color_plaque)
                intersection = self.find_intersection(segmented_image, masked)
                haralick = self.haralick(segmented_image, 'contrast')


    def find_intersection(self, mask, image):
        mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        masked_image = image * mask
        Image.fromarray(masked_image).show()


    def create_mask_plaque(self, image, color_plaque):
        COLOR1_RANGE = [(30, 0, 0), (255, 50, 50)]  # Blue in BGR, [(low), (high)].

        if color_plaque == 'green':
            COLOR1_RANGE = [(0, 30, 0), (50, 255, 50)]
        elif color_plaque == 'red':
            COLOR1_RANGE = [(0, 0, 30), (50, 50, 255)]
        elif color_plaque == 'blue':
            COLOR1_RANGE = [(30, 0, 0), (255, 50, 50)]
        elif color_plaque == 'b&w':
            COLOR1_RANGE = [(0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 255)]

        mask = cv2.inRange(image, COLOR1_RANGE[0], COLOR1_RANGE[1])
        only_plaque = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(only_plaque, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        thresh = 255 - thresh

        # Morph open with a elliptical shaped kernel
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
        opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)
        Image.fromarray(opening).show()

        return opening

    def haralick(self, image, function):
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        P = skimage.feature.texture.greycomatrix(image, [1], [0], levels=256, symmetric=False, normed=False)
        result = skimage.feature.texture.greycoprops(P, prop=function)

        return result[0][0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    texture_wavelets = TextureWavelets()
    directory_segmentation = 'D:/CTU/new_segmentation_data/references/trans'
    directory_originals = 'D:/CTU/new_segmentation_data/data/trans'
    n_displays = 2
    # options for lumen and plaque colors: green, red, blue, b&w
    texture_wavelets.access_to_images(directory_segmentation, directory_originals, n_displays, 'b&w')
```

The problem is that the find_intersection function returns me this:

[image]

It's gray with no texture, and what I need is the texture...

Comment: please show your attempts. Without this context (e.g. how images are represented) this question cannot be answered

Comment: @Marat ok!! I edit my post now:)

Comment: @Georgia Please let me know if my answer helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("ring_bg.png")
mask = cv2.imread("ring_mask.png")

h, w, _ = img.shape
mask = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), (w, h)) # Resize image
bg = np.zeros_like(img, 'uint8') # Black background

def crop(img, bg, mask):
    fg = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask)            
    fg_back_inv = cv2.bitwise_or(bg, bg, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask))
    return cv2.bitwise_or(fg, fg_back_inv)

cv2.imshow("Image", crop(img, bg, mask))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]